# How to update a date value that is blank on MSSQL?

Tags: php, sql-server

I am creating a form that extracts user info, and the users can update their info if needs be.  On the form there are two date fields, the second field is optional.  So when the user clicks UPDATE and the second date field is blank, in MSSQL database it updates the date_two field with "01/01/1970".  I am using PHP with MSSQL, so in the code I have:

```
if(isset($_POST['update']) {

   $date_two = $_POST['date_two'];

   if($date_two == "")
      $date_two == NULL;
   else
     $date_two = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date_two) );

   UPDATE table SET date_two = CAST('$date_two' as DATE2);

}
```

The resulted entry is 01/01/1970, instead of NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check if your input date value is a emprty  string  ('') and manage for null  because if the value of your var is not null (also an empty string)
the update produce a date value

```
    UPDATE table SET date_two = (case when  '$date_two' = '' then NULL 
                          else  CAST('$date_two' as DATE2)
                          end);
```

anyway  you should not use php  var in your sql command  you are at rusk for sqlinjection  .. take a lool at you db driver fior prepared command and binding param   ..

Comment: @Jdeleon  .. answer  updated  with  () around case  condition